# Initialising variables in an init_vars() function

Tags: python, global-variables

This code doesn't initializes the variables that I expect to be initialized.

```py
a,b,c = [None]*3

def __init_abc():
    a="a"
    b="b"
    c="c"
    
def print_abc():
    __init_abc()
    print(a,b,c)
    
print_abc()
```

Output is:

```
None None None
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the `__init_abc` function you need to specify the global variables `a`, `b`, `c` otherwise the variables are presumed to be local to the function.

```py
a,b,c = [None]*3

def __init_abc():
    global a,b,c
    a="a"
    b="b"
    c="c"
    
def print_abc():
    __init_abc()
    print(a,b,c)
    
print_abc()
```

Output:

```
a b c
```